# How to resolve ReSharper's "unused property" warning on properties solely for Display/Value Members?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have defined two properties, "Name" and "ID", for an object which I use for the DisplayMember and ValueMember of a ComboBox with a BindingList datasource.

I recently installed [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to evaluate it. ReSharper is giving me warnings on the object that the two properties are unused.

Sample code:

```
BindingList<ClassSample> SampleList = new BindingList<ClassSample>();
// populate SampleList
cmbSampleSelector.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmdSampleSelector.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbSampleSelector.DataSource = SampleList;

private class ClassSample
{
    private string _name;
    private string _id;

    public string Name // ReSharper believes this property is unused
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public string ID // ReSharper believes this property is unused
    {
        get {return _id; }
    }

    public ClassSample(string Name, string ID)
    {
        _name = Name;
        _id = ID;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is ReSharper clueless about this particular usage?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way that JetBrains suggests that you solve these issues is with their attributes (available from ReSharper -> Options -> Code Annotations).  Add the attributes to your project/solution and then mark these properties with the [UsedImplicitly attribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute).  ReSharper will now assume that the properties are used via Reflection or late bound or whatever.

Comment: I suggest you show an example, including how to get the attributes. Some people don't get this.

Comment: This will also work for Attributes (using the MeansImplicitUse attribute). 
Example: [MeansImplicitUse((ImplicitUseKindFlags.Instantiated|ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)] on an attribute marking a dependency injection

Comment: To use ReSharper code annotations, one must include the declarations in the project. For more information see [JetBrains page on the topic](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html). For a property that's used in reflection, I found the attribute I needed was `[UsedImplicitly]`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to David's answer, in Resharper 8.x and later, add the `Resharper.ExternalAnnotations` plugin to Resharper in Visual Studio `(Resharper -> Extension Manager)`.

When Resharper next complains about an `unused property`, you can then click on the left hand purple pyramid and select `Used Implicitly`, which will decorate the field / property with an [`UsedImplicitlyAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute).

[image: Resharper UsedImplicitly]

You can then either directly add a reference to `JetBrains.Annotations.dll` in your project, or you can choose to let Resharper add a small `Annotations.cs` file to your project containing the `Attribute` definition (and others like `NotNullAttribute`). The `Annotations.cs` file is located under the `Properties` icon in the solution folder.

[image: Adding Resharper Annotations.cs to your project]

As an aside, it would have been nice to be to be able to add a `Description` to the attribute as well, e.g. `[UsedImplicitly(Description="Used by NUnit Theory / Reflected by Xyz, etc")]`, so in the interim we'll need to comment.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the properties via reflection (this is what the code above amounts to). ReSharper can only analyze static behavior (with some very limited exceptions), so it can't know that these properties are actually being used.

You can simply suppress the warnings though. Just click on the property name and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then choose the option to suppress the warning. This will add a `// ReSharper disable` comment around the variable name.

Comment: I have discovered the suppress warning comments, however the example is fairly simplified; there are many such comboboxes with various objects, etc. I'd prefer not to have to add so many comments. Is there some other way to set Display and Value Members that don't rely on reflection?

Comment: JYelton: Not that I'm aware of. As a last resort you could also suppress the warning globally.

Comment: You can suppress warnings at the file level, too.

Answer (score 1):

When things are used via reflection (which I imagine is what the framework is doing in your case), ReSharper can't tell (at least in it's current form).

Comment: Is there some other way to set Display and Value Members that don't rely on reflection?

Comment: Nope, I usually suppress with comment, then move the comment begin/close pair to suppress for the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

To install ReSharper annotations:

```
PM> Install-Package JetBrains.Annotations
```

Then you can add the attributes by typing `[UsedImplicitly]` or by using the context menu ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQEgR.png)).

Code sample:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
class ClassSample
{
    private string _name;
    private string _id;

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public string Name // ReSharper believes this property is unused
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public string ID // ReSharper believes this property is unused
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public ClassSample(string Name, string ID)
    {
        _name = Name;
        _id = ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did use the ReSharper mechanism for commenting out that check for a specific instance which I also needed, using this process with ReSharper:

[image: Using ReSharper menu to disable warning once]

This worked great for what I needed in this where I am using an implicit mechanism for setting the value but do not want to turn it off project wide.